# Trying to find out the path of my images while trying to map over .json file, create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a  mapping function that iterates through my .json data. 
`vechileData.Data.map((i) => <img  className = "MainImage" src ={vechileData.Data[i].img}/>`

I found out that the main problem was that my `img` variable in my .json file was incorrect and it would render a broken image.

Incorrect | `"img": "/imgFolder/Car.jpg",`

Correct |  `"img": "/static/media/Car.32adf318.jpg",`

I found out that correct path by opening the image in my `localhost server` and copying that path.

If I start to load my .json file with many images, what is the best way to find my image path? I'm guessing `webpack` bundles all my images and places it in the `stack/media` folder at build time. What about the  random numbers `32adf318.jpg`.

Comment: vechileData.Data.map((item,index) => <img  className = "MainImage" src ={item}/>

Answer (score 0):

### `Array.prototype.map`'s first argument is `currentValue`

I believe what's wrong with your code is that you are misusing `.map`. The correct use would be:

```
vehicleData.Data.map(currentVehicle => (
  <img className='MainImage' src={currentVehicle.img} />
))
```

[`Array.prototype.map`'s callback takes the following arguments:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

- `currentValue`: The current element being processed in the array.
- `index`: The index of the current element being processed in the array.
- `array`: The array map was called upon.

FYI, it's **"vehicle"** not **"vechile"**.

### Filling JSON file with a list of images

As for filling up your JSON file with a list of images, I would suggest writing a small script to get all the names from a folder that will hold your images (`assets/vehicles/` perhaps) and running it alongside webpack:

```
array=($(ls path/to/folder))

output="\"vehicleData\": {\n\t\"Data\": [\n"
for file in ${array[@]}; do
  output="$output\t\t\"$file\",\n"
done
output="${output::-3}\n\t]\n}"

echo -e $output
```

**Output:**

```
"vehicleData": {
        "Data": [
                "headerBackground.jpg",
                "hollow-arrow.svg",
                "logoC.svg",
                "senior1.jpg",
                "senior2.jpg"
        ]
}
```

**Note:** You may have to `import/require` the file.

Comment: Got it. Code looks much more simpler to read now, but I'm still getting a broken image thumbnail when I try to load the image by calling `"img": "/imgFolder/Car.jpg",`